# Hiding Text in to Image

Tags: vb.net

Hi everyone. I have a problem in hiding text into a Jpeg image. I convert the image to binary and the text into binary. I want to swap the last bit for each byte in the image with a bit in my string message but the problem is the image doesn't appear successfully.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
Dim myImage As Image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("Images/image.jpg"))

'Image to byte[]
Dim imgMemoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
Dim imgByteArray As Byte() = Nothing
myImage.Save(imgMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
imgByteArray = imgMemoryStream.GetBuffer()

'Byte[] to image
imgMemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(imgByteArray)
myImage = Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgMemoryStream)

'Show it and check if the image is accordant with E:\VBproject\1.jpg.

Dim ln As Long
Dim str2 As String = "h"
Dim strArry As Byte() = New Byte(str2.Length) {}
strArry = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str2)
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim b As Long = ((UBound(strArry) + 1) * 8) - 1
Dim Binstr(b) As String
For Each strbt As Byte In strArry
    Dim binnarystr As String = Convert.ToString(strbt, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c)

    For Each Chr As Char In binnarystr
        Binstr(i) += Chr

        i += 1
    Next
Next


'=====================================================
Dim ii As Integer = 1


'=================================================================
i = 0

Dim NewImageArray(imgByteArray.Length) As Byte
For Each Bt As Byte In imgByteArray
    If i < UBound(Binstr) + 1 Then
        Dim Bin As String = Convert.ToString(Bt, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c)

        Dim str As String

        Bin = Bin.Remove(7, 1)
        str = Bin.ToString() & Binstr(i).ToString()

        ii = 1
        ln = 0
        For Each Chr As Char In str
            If ii = 1 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 128
            ElseIf ii = 2 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 64
            ElseIf ii = 3 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 32
            ElseIf ii = 4 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 16
            ElseIf ii = 5 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 8
            ElseIf ii = 6 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 4
            ElseIf ii = 7 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 2
            ElseIf ii = 8 Then
                ln += CInt(Chr.ToString()) * 1
            End If
            ii += 1
        Next
        NewImageArray(i) = ln
        ii = 1
        ln = 0
    Else
            NewImageArray(i) = Bt
    End If
    i += 1
Next

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("Images/Alpha.jpg"), NewImageArray, False)
```

Comment: `.jpg` is a lossy compression algorithm for images. You can't just swap bits like that. Try using a `.bmp` instead, and see if your code works.

Comment: Voting to leave open. Sure, it's a localized question, but I can see somebody else experiencing similar confusion. And it has one very good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems here.

First, you're breaking the header. Image files typically have two sections: a header describing attributes of the image, such as color pallette, size, compression level, EXIF data, etc, and a data section which contains the actual pixel data. By starting with the first byte, you are changing information in the header, which can make the image completely invalid.

The second problem is that you're breaking the image pixel data. The image data itself is, in most formats, compressed. When you change one bit of a compressed byte, that change has a magnified effect in the decompressed results, if the compressed data is even still valid for that compression algorithm... you might not be able to decompress the data at all any more.

Finally, one bit per byte is too much change. You're rewriting an eighth of the total, and that's quite a lot. One bit per pixel is a better place to start, and even that may be a "bit" much.

What you need to do for this scheme to work is deal with pixel data directly. This means you need to load the image not just as a byte array, but respecting the image's properties and decompressing any pixel data, as if you were to display the image on screen. Then you can read through the pixels, change one bit for each pixel, and re-save the image back to it's original format.

Comment: One more problem: `imgMemoryStream.GetBuffer()` returns the internal buffer which maybe greater than actual bytes. It should be `imgMemoryStream.ToArray()`